# Reducing the line spacing of math environments that support multi-lined contents

Tags: amsmath, line-spacing, mathtools

I’m trying to reduce the line spacing of “math environments that support multi-lined contents” back to `singlespacing` in a `onehalfspacing` document. I’m using the `setspace` and `mathtools` packages.

**Added**: By “math environments that support multi-lined contents”, I mean *any math environments that allow typesetting multiple lines of contents*, no matter whether they are in inline or display math mode. This includes, for instance, the `matrix` environment in inline math mode.

My current two-step solution is

1. creating a macro that does `\linespread{1}\selectfont` at the beginning of each math environment that can be fixed this way, and
2. writing special patches for those that cannot be fixed by Step 1.

This solution produces the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[draft]{article}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}
\setstretch{2}% more text spacing just for exaggeration
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
% Let the patches begin!
\makeatletter
\def\mathlinespread{\setspace@singlespace}% 1 by default, can be changed
\newcommand*\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading[1]{%
  \AtBeginEnvironment{#1}{%
    \linespread{\mathlinespread}\selectfont\ignorespaces}}
% TeX
\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{array}
% amsmath
\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{matrix}
\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{pmatrix}
\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{bmatrix}
\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{Bmatrix}
\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{vmatrix}
\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{Vmatrix}
\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{cases}
\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{aligned}
\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{alignedat}
\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{gathered}
% special care
\patchcmd{\start@gather}
  {\collect@body}
  {\linespread{\mathlinespread}\selectfont\collect@body}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\start@align}
  {\collect@body}
  {\linespread{\mathlinespread}\selectfont\collect@body}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\start@multline}
  {\collect@body}
  {\linespread{\mathlinespread}\selectfont\collect@body}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\gather@split}
  {\spread@equation}
  {\linespread{\mathlinespread}\selectfont\spread@equation}
  {}{}
% mathtools
\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{matrix*}
\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{pmatrix*}
\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{bmatrix*}
\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{Bmatrix*}
\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{vmatrix*}
\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{Vmatrix*}
\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{cases*}
\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{dcases}
\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{dcases*}
\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{rcases}
\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{rcases*}
\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{drcases}
\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{drcases*}
\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{multlined}
\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{lgathered}
\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{rgathered}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
Subarray and small matrices are not affected by \verb|\setstretch{2}|
to start with:
$\begin{psmallmatrix*}[r] -a & b \\ c & -d \end{psmallmatrix*}$ and
\[
\sum_{\substack{i=1\\i\neq j}}^n x_i
\]
With my patches, matrices and cases work fine in inline math mode:
$\begin{Vmatrix} -a & b \\ c & -d \end{Vmatrix}$,
$\begin{drcases*} -a & Words \\ c & Text \end{drcases*} = f(x)$.
If I patch \verb|\env@matrix| and \verb|\env@cases| directly, then the
patches only apply to \verb|amsmath|'s environments, not to
\verb|mathtools|.

Here are some inner multi-line math environments:
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a_1, a_1, a_1, a_1, \\
a_1, a_1, a_1, \\
a_1, a_1, \\
\end{split} \quad
\begin{gathered}
a_1, a_1, a_1, a_1, \\
a_1, a_1, a_1, \\
a_1, a_1, \\
\end{gathered} \quad
\begin{lgathered}
a_1, a_1, a_1, a_1, \\
a_1, a_1, a_1, \\
a_1, a_1, \\
\end{lgathered}
\end{equation}
And an outer:
\begin{align}
a & = b + c \\
  & = d + e + f
\end{align}
\begin{singlespace}
Note that \verb|\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{split}| will not work!
Yet the method applies to \verb|aligned|, \verb|alignedat|, \verb|gathered|,
\verb|multlined|, \verb|lgathered| and \verb|rgathered|.
Also, the patch for \verb|split| happens after \verb|\collect@body|,
while those for \verb|gather|, \verb|align|, \verb|multline| happen before
\verb|\collect@body|.

Note that \verb|aligned| and \verb|alignedat| can be fixed by patching
\verb|\start@aligned| right before \verb|\spread@equation|, exactly like
\verb|split|. However, I only know how to fix \verb|gathered| by using
\verb|\RestoreMathEnvironmentLeading{gathered}|. The patching code is
structurally inconsistent anyway.
\end{singlespace}

\end{document}
```

[image: Illustration]

Even though I think I’ve covered all environments (some may suggest that the problem is solved), I’m dissatisfied with my solution for 3 reasons:

1. It turns out that [`align*` is a pseudo-environment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/53793), hence a special patch is needed. But the three special patches for `\start@gather`, `\start@align` and `\start@multline` are drastically different from [the one for `split`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/199323), with the first three happening *before* `\collect@body` while the last one *after* `\collect@body`. Why the inconsistency?
2. It turns out that `matrix` and friends from `amsmath` are also pseudo-environments, so they may be fixed by simply patching `\env@matrix`. The same goes for `cases` by patching `\env@cases`; for `aligned` and `alignedat` by patching `\start@aligned`. However, if used, the positions of these patches vary, and I fear this would cause undesired side-effect.
3. The method in Reason 2 doesn’t apply to `matrix*` and friends, `cases*` and friends from `mathtools`. Also, I can’t find the way to patch `gathered` from `amsmath` in that fashion (Note that `\end{gathered}` is actually `\endaligned`, again, a pseudo-environment).

---

### Is there a better and more consistent way to reduce the line spacing of these “math environments that support multi-lined contents”?

**Added**: By “better and more consistent”, I mean *patches that are quantitatively minimum and structurally consistent*.

You may have noticed that the `subarray` (includes `\substack`), `smallmatrix` and friends, and `eqnarray` environments are left out in my solution. For the first two environments, the line spacing is set according to `\baselineskip...` (p. 33 of the `amsmath` manual). This prevents `setspace` from changing their line spacing, which is desired. For `eqnarray`, well, I’d never, ever use `eqnarray`.

It seems to me that the concisest solution would be patching *the code* that governs `\\`.

---

Here’s an exhaustive list (I guess?) of “math environments that support multi-lined contents” provided by the `mathtools` package (and by the `amsmath` package, which is loaded by `mathtools`; and by TeX itself):

#### TeX

- `array`;

#### `amsmath`

- `matrix`, `pmatrix`, `bmatrix`, `Bmatrix`, `vmatrix`, `Vmatrix`;
- `cases`;
- `aligned`, `alignedat`;
- `gathered`;
- `gather` and friend;
- `align` and friends;
- `multline` and friend;
- `split`;

#### `mathtools`

- `matrix*`, `pmatrix*`, `bmatrix*`, `Bmatrix*`, `vmatrix*`, `Vmatrix*`;
- `cases*`, `dcases`, `dcases*`, `rcases`, `rcases*`, `drcases`, `drcases*`;
- `multlined`;
- `lgathered`, `rgathered`;

Comment: Have you considered setting the option `nodisplayskipstretch` when loading the `setspace` package? Separately, did you see [this posting](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/137004/5001) and, in particular, the answers provided by @Herbert and @egreg?

Comment: @Mico Yes and yes. I didn’t include `nodisplayskipstretch` simply because I wanted to provide a simple MWE. The actual goal is using 1.2 leading to font size ratio for math and 1.5 ratio for CJK text. The solution by @Herbert produces warnings. The solution by @egreg is mentioned at the beginning of Reason 2.

Comment: Which kinds of warnings do you get with @Herbert's method?

Comment: @Mico The warning is mentioned by @egreg in the comments of @Herbert’s answer:`LaTeX Font Warning: Command \normalsize invalid in math mode on input line ...`. On another note, @Herbert’s solution doesn’t cover inline matrices — I know that using `matrix` and friends in inline text is a typography disasters, and `smallmatrix` and friends should be used. But notice that the line spacing of `smallmatrix` and friends is *not* affected because of the way it is constructed. Same goes with `subarray`.

Comment: Your posting contains a very broad question -- "Is there a better and more consistent way to reduce the line spacing" -- but what you might deem to be an acceptable answer is somewhat elusive. The warning related to Herbert's method is just that: a warning, and a fairly harmless one at that. AFAICT, your initial posting did not mention inline math mode matrices. To wit, the title of your posting refers to multi-line math environments; that's quite the opposite of inline math stuff, isn't it? You may want to edit your posting a bit to make it clearer what your focus is.

Comment: @Mico Thanks for the suggestions. The phrase “multi-line math environments” has a somewhat different meaning to me (can’t find a better phrase) and I thought my MWE illustrated my point. I’ve added clarification. I also elaborated a bit on my question.

Comment: Thanks. It would be nice if your revised MWE contained two or three examples of inline or display-math materials whose contents should be rendered single-spaced. Otherwise, too many decisions are left to likely pointless and time-wasting guesswork.